# Meyers singleton destructs earlier than last usage

Tags: c++, gcc, singleton

I faced problem with Meyers singleton implemented this way in dynamic library A.so on Ubuntu:

```
class Singleton
{
/*some functionality*/
}

Singleton& getSingleton(); // in header file

Singleton& getSingleton() // in .cpp file
{
    static Singleton value;
    return value;
}
```

And function `getSingleton()` is called in constructor and destructor of object of type `User` of **other** library B.so, like this:

```
class User
{
    User()
    {
        getSingleton().addSmth();
    }
    ~User()
    {
        getSingleton().removeSmth();
    }
    /*some other functionality*/
};
```

Object of class User is created as **static** object of some function in B.so.

So, I faced with destroying `Singleton` object **before** calling it from other `User` class's destructor.

My project has multiple libraries, it is built with CMake and gcc-10.3 on Ubuntu 20.04. I need help with fixing of Singleton's object lifetime

I checked the same project in Visual Studio on Windows 10 and it works well

Comment: Can you provide the declaration/definition of the other object? Is it a  mere static object or  a singleton or a function local static?

Comment: @Red.Wave sure, I updated description

Comment: @user17732522 sorry for non-expressive example. I meant that in ctor and dtor of ```User``` we add and remove something to ```Singleton``` object. ```Singleton``` objects itself is default-initializable

Comment: @IvanIvlev Ok, then it will depend on how exactly `User` object(s) are created.

Comment: @IvanIvlev it provides the type(decltype) of other static, not its declaration/definition. Are you certain it is a function local static?

Comment: @Red.Wave @user17732522 ```User``` class object is static object of B.so function

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the order of destruction is the reverse of construction. So you must make sure `Singleton` is initialized before the other static object that's using it (let's call it `SingletonClient`). So, something like this:

```
struct SingletonClient {
  SingletonClient() {
    getSingleton(); // makes sure the other object is constructed before this one
  }
};
```